# Forgot Programming Logic after mental breakdown

Tags: algorithm, logic

Backstory - Had depression since a long time was on medication but high school finals, ACTs, bunch of other exams along with work pressure triggered something that caused a nasty mental breakdown. Also, the number of pills I was being fed by my doctor to study longer hours which is pretty common for students in Asia.

So basically after that happened, I was not able to look at screens or even read books on my own without having hallucinations and questioning my own existence. This lasted 3 months and took another 4 to come back to normal.

The thing is my memory has been wiped out I can't remember stuff clearly that happened before the mental breakdown, especially stuff from 7th grade till high school (which is when I learned to code and tinker with computers).I even got an internship, won a high school hackathon, was working on a web scraping project and a puzzle game.

What I have realized is I still remember stuff like syntax but my brain can't seem to figure out how to apply them even things like for loops in simple basic level programming problems like printing shapes made of characters in cmd.

This stuff used to be really easy to work before, so I want to get back to the level I was at because programming and messing with computers has been the only thing I have loved since I was a teenager and not getting even simple stuff is making me loose sleep.

The worse thing is I have enrolled into a computer engineering degree and not that I would be going into my second year of it where we have subjects like data structures, Turing machines, etc. I may have to drop out if things keep going the way they are.

I don't know where to start again, since I just can't seem to apply what I know like I used to to things. I have turned to this sub before for troubleshooting, so I hope you awesome people will guide me out through this hell hole.

I forgot to mention I may lose out on an upcoming internship.

I hate how the only thing i liked doing is not working anymore

TL:DR ; HAVE TO START FROM THE BOTTOM again to think like a dev due to a mental breakdown and have no idea where to begin again.

Comment: Sounds like you've had to overcome some significant challenges. Having something like this to motivate you can be helpful. However, Stack Overflow is primarily for troubleshooting specific technical problems in code and so people here aren't in  a good position here generally to tutor, coach, advise,  or do career or one-on-one counseling.  Maybe you can reach  out to a counselor at school, or get some sort of career or life counseling from people who specialize in that kind of thing. It will probably be more effective and help set you on an optimal path.

Comment: In many cases things get better with practice, if you're not overly anxious about the results. If you're feeling foggy, or have forgotten a lot it can be disappointing and daunting, however, if you make small goals, get inspired by things, practice and persist I am sure it will improve, probably faster than you realize right now.

Comment: One good starting point is to understand basic code snippets. You could start writing later after you are comfortable with reading some code.

Comment: Online courses can be helpful. Audio and visual may help in easy learning process.

Comment: I am no doctor so read with prejudice To help with concentration use meditation but only beginner stuff for example try JOGA 10min per day does miracles but only if it is doable for you if it brings discomfort stop. Because after brain shock like yours things that work on majority of population may not work for you anymore. Brain is so redundant that is really hard to wipe something out from it (unless the memory attachment is chemically dependent  on chemicals that you no longer have like your pills you used to take) So when you start coding with time some memories should come back to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific programming problem, but rather asking how to re-learn the practice of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Starting all over again could be tough. Start by challenging yourself by completing simple exercises every day and gradually taking a more difficult problems/exercises. There are many resources out there online where they give you exercises on what you want.

Self studying is usually how every developer goes about. Joining communities like this can also help you refresh your mind with solving technical problems. Try browsing in this website and answering different questions. Start with the simple ones.

I pursued an IT course as well with zero programming skills, but with time, effort, and perseverance, you can learn to code and regain your knowledge back again. Who knows, you might even remember some of your programming skills.

ALSO, there are different languages or branches when it comes to developing. Choose the language you want to know about and focus on that until you master it. Then you may start learning a different language

Here's a sample site which offers different exercises.
http://www.programmr.com/